# How much memory an app can use on iPad?

Tags: ipad

Currently I am writing an iPad app. I am using a lot of images in this app around 40 MB of images!
This app works fine in simulator but crashing on device. I think the problem is with memory.

I wanted to know how much memory I can use on iPad?

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: You can use instruments to check how much memory is being used by your app. Run instruments on the simulator so you can see peek usage, and then on the device so you can see at what point the app is failing.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to keep your total app memory usage under 10M at all times. The way you do that is by not writing code that allocates lots and lots of memory for decompressed images at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that 40MB of image files on disk is far more when put in memory. On disk they are compressed but once you load it into memory you use just as much memory as a uncompressed image. If I remember right its (width x height x (bits per pixel/8)) = mem usage so for a full screen image (1024x768x(16/8)) = 1,572,864 so around 1.5 MB of RAM while on disk it may only be a couple hundred KB.

Comment: width x height x (ceil ( bits per pixel / 8 ) )

Comment: Thanks! I am compressing the images again and trying to get the size under 10 MB  or less. I'll check and post here...

Comment: Compressing the image won't help RAM usage. Only lowering the images' resolution will help that.

Comment: jamone is correct. Either reduce the width and/or height of your image, or reduce the color space of your image. There's a nifty tool for Mac OS X available, that helps you do that called [Image Alpha](http://pngmini.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The iPad has 256 MB of memory, and of which, only around 100 to 120 are usable in an application. Note that this number is variable as the VM releases memory from previous applications, and could be less if you're using apps like iPod in the background.

My suggestion, look at what you can do to reduce the size of your images, through different resolutions, lower quality images, or such.

Comment: Thanks! I am compressing the images again and trying to get the size under 10 MB or less. I'll check and post here...